# SplittableDoFn when using BigQueryIOI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

When reading large tables from BigQuery, I find that only one worker is sometime active and Dataflow then actively kills other workers (then starts ramping up once the large PCollection requires processing - losing time)

So I wonder:
1. Will SplittableDoFn (SDF) alleviate this problem when applied to BigQueryIO
2. Will SDF's increase the use of the num_workers (and stop them from being shut down)?
3. Are SDF's available in Python (yet) and even in Java, available beyond just FileIO?

The real objective here is to reduce total processing time (quicker creation of the PCollection using more workers, faster execution of the DAG as Dataflow then scales up from --num_workers to --max_workers)

Comment: The BigQueryIO read will be doing a two step processes, first it will do a export of the table into GCS and once thats done it will start the reading. If you look at the logs I think you should be able to see the Job being submitted and I think it should also show the completion time. Would be good to see how much of the total time your reducing is actually this export step.

Comment: PS : that should read the BQ job being submitted.

Comment: Thanks Rez. It makes sense, especially if BQ is landing stuff to storage - so direct reading might make a difference. However, it probably does not address the fact that a lot of workers will remain idle and therefore pre-emptive shutdown of these workers might occur. But - will give it a whirl first - then report back

Comment: Another option to explore will be https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/